# How to solve this "Compile Error: Invalid or Unqualified Reference"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm totally new to vba macros and cant seem to find a solution to my error. I have the following code:

```
Sub BuilderUpdate()

Range("B2").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("B2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D2").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("C2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F2").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("D2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H2").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("E2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B3").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("F2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D3").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("G2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F3").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("H2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H3").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("I2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B4").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("J2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D4").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("K2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F4").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("L2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H4").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("M2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B5").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("N2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D5").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("O2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F5").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("P2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H5").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("Q2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B6").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("R2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D6").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("S2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F6").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("T2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H6").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("U2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B7").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("V2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D7").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("W2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F7").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("X2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H7").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("Y2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B8").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("Z2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D8").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AA2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F8").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AB2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H8").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AC2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B9").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AD2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D9").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AE2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F9").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AF2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H9").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AG2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B10").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AH2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D10").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AI2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F10").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AJ2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H10").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AK2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B11").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AL2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D11").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AM2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F11").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AN2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H11").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AO2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B12").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AP2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D12").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AQ2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F12").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AR2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H12").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AS2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B13").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AT2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D13").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AU2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F13").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AV2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H13").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AW2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B14").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AX2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D14").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AY2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F14").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("AZ2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H14").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BA2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B15").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BB2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D15").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BC2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F15").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BD2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H15").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BE2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B16").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BF2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D16").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BG2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F16").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BH2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H16").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("BI2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

However when attempting to run the code i get an error saying "Compile Error: Invalid or Unqualified Reference" and it points to the first line of the macro as such https://puu.sh/GHfuN/45afb283fd.png

I feel like there is a simple solution but i'm totally not seeing it.

Comment: Are the .Pastespecials really on a separate line or is that just a formatting issue on this website.

Comment: if i had them on the same line, they gave me a compile error. only way i could get it to work was to put them on a newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Refactored

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuilderUpdate()

    Dim Target As Variant
    Target = Array("B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2", "J2", "K2", _
                   "L2", "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2", "R2", "S2", "T2", "U2", _
                   "V2", "W2", "X2", "Y2", "Z2", "AA2", "AB2", "AC2", "AD2", _
                   "AE2", "AF2", "AG2", "AH2", "AI2", "AJ2", "AK2", "AL2", _
                   "AM2", "AN2", "AO2", "AP2", "AQ2", "AR2", "AS2", "AT2", _
                   "AU2", "AV2", "AW2", "AX2", "AY2", "AZ2", "BA2", "BB2", _
                   "BC2", "BD2", "BE2", "BF2", "BG2", "BH2", "BI2")
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = Array("B2", "D2", "F2", "H2", "B3", "D3", "F3", "H3", "B4", "D4", _
                   "F4", "H4", "B5", "D5", "F5", "H5", "B6", "D6", "F6", "H6", _
                   "B7", "D7", "F7", "H7", "B8", "D8", "F8", "H8", "B9", "D9", _
                   "F9", "H9", "B10", "D10", "F10", "H10", "B11", "D11", _
                   "F11", "H11", "B12", "D12", "F12", "H12", "B13", "D13", _
                   "F13", "H13", "B14", "D14", "F14", "H14", "B15", "D15", _
                   "F15", "H15", "B16", "D16", "F16", "H16")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Pack")
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(Source) To UBound(Source)
        ws.Range(Target(n)).Value = Range(Source(n)).Value
    Next n
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```

- In Excel you could write down the cell addresses in two columns and then use formulas to get the following string below the worksheet reference:

  ```
  ="    ws.Range("""&A1&""").Value = Range("""&B1&""").Value"
  ```

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub BuilderUpdateQF()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Pack")

    ws.Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value
    ws.Range("C2").Value = Range("D2").Value
    ws.Range("D2").Value = Range("F2").Value
    ws.Range("E2").Value = Range("H2").Value
    ws.Range("F2").Value = Range("B3").Value
    ws.Range("G2").Value = Range("D3").Value
    ws.Range("H2").Value = Range("F3").Value
    ws.Range("I2").Value = Range("H3").Value
    ws.Range("J2").Value = Range("B4").Value
    ws.Range("K2").Value = Range("D4").Value
    ws.Range("L2").Value = Range("F4").Value
    ws.Range("M2").Value = Range("H4").Value
    ws.Range("N2").Value = Range("B5").Value
    ws.Range("O2").Value = Range("D5").Value
    ws.Range("P2").Value = Range("F5").Value
    ws.Range("Q2").Value = Range("H5").Value
    ws.Range("R2").Value = Range("B6").Value
    ws.Range("S2").Value = Range("D6").Value
    ws.Range("T2").Value = Range("F6").Value
    ws.Range("U2").Value = Range("H6").Value
    ws.Range("V2").Value = Range("B7").Value
    ws.Range("W2").Value = Range("D7").Value
    ws.Range("X2").Value = Range("F7").Value
    ws.Range("Y2").Value = Range("H7").Value
    ws.Range("Z2").Value = Range("B8").Value
    ws.Range("AA2").Value = Range("D8").Value
    ws.Range("AB2").Value = Range("F8").Value
    ws.Range("AC2").Value = Range("H8").Value
    ws.Range("AD2").Value = Range("B9").Value
    ws.Range("AE2").Value = Range("D9").Value
    ws.Range("AF2").Value = Range("F9").Value
    ws.Range("AG2").Value = Range("H9").Value
    ws.Range("AH2").Value = Range("B10").Value
    ws.Range("AI2").Value = Range("D10").Value
    ws.Range("AJ2").Value = Range("F10").Value
    ws.Range("AK2").Value = Range("H10").Value
    ws.Range("AL2").Value = Range("B11").Value
    ws.Range("AM2").Value = Range("D11").Value
    ws.Range("AN2").Value = Range("F11").Value
    ws.Range("AO2").Value = Range("H11").Value
    ws.Range("AP2").Value = Range("B12").Value
    ws.Range("AQ2").Value = Range("D12").Value
    ws.Range("AR2").Value = Range("F12").Value
    ws.Range("AS2").Value = Range("H12").Value
    ws.Range("AT2").Value = Range("B13").Value
    ws.Range("AU2").Value = Range("D13").Value
    ws.Range("AV2").Value = Range("F13").Value
    ws.Range("AW2").Value = Range("H13").Value
    ws.Range("AX2").Value = Range("B14").Value
    ws.Range("AY2").Value = Range("D14").Value
    ws.Range("AZ2").Value = Range("F14").Value
    ws.Range("BA2").Value = Range("H14").Value
    ws.Range("BB2").Value = Range("B15").Value
    ws.Range("BC2").Value = Range("D15").Value
    ws.Range("BD2").Value = Range("F15").Value
    ws.Range("BE2").Value = Range("H15").Value
    ws.Range("BF2").Value = Range("B16").Value
    ws.Range("BG2").Value = Range("D16").Value
    ws.Range("BH2").Value = Range("F16").Value
    ws.Range("BI2").Value = Range("H16").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Sir, your refactored code seems like the best solution for me to use so far. May i inquire as to why the arrays are split into different lines and ended with a underscore?

Comment: @Four: It's called a line break. That's how you write a line in several lines. You use a `space` and an `underscore`. Of course you can write them in one line, but I like to restrict my lines of code to 80 characters for a better readability.

Comment: Thank you. This refactor also speeds up the copy time considerably.

Comment: I think it's the same speed as the 'Quick Fix' solution, but it's definitely much faster then the copy/paste solutions. It is called  *Copying by Assignment*. But you can only copy values in this way.

Comment: I decided to just do the refactor anyway of quick fix. Only takes me extra 5 mins to keep the code simple and short :D. and yes values is all i need to copy

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) 2 issues with your code:

**(1)** You can use the `Copy`-method of a Range in two ways:
**(1A)** The first method is to provide a parameter that gives the destination of the `Copy`. So writing

```
Range("B2").Copy Worksheets("Pack").Range("B2")
```

copies the cell B2 of the Activesheet to the cell B2 of sheet Pack, including formatting. This is simulating the Copy&Paste you do manually in Excel. The difference is that after that the Paste-Buffer is empty and you cannot issue another `Paste`-command with it

**(1B)** The second method is to use `Copy` without parameter. This is like the Copy-Command in Excel. You can issue one or more `PasteSpecial` after that:

```
Range("B2").Copy 
Worksheets("Pack").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Pack").Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

However, if you just want to copy a value from one cell to the other, it's much simpler to use

```
Worksheets("Pack").Range("B2") = Range("B2")
```

**(2)** The syntax using a leading dot (like `.PasteSpecial`) is valid only when you use it in combination with a `With` - clause.

```
With Worksheets("Pack").Range("B2")
    Range("B2").Copy 
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Now the leading `.` will tell VBA that you use a member of the object that you declared in the `With`-statement (in your case the cell B2 of sheet Pack). It's a matter of taste if or if not to use a `With`-statement.

Comment: Cheers, i think i was not clear enough in my original post. The code is for copying data from sheet 1 to sheet 2. The block i originally posted is repeated another 500 times with different copy and paste cells. hence why i originally did it this way. I also have formatting on sheet 1 which i do not want to be transferred to sheet 2 hence why the paste special. 1A achieves a simple copy but also copies formatting. 1B looks like it would copy Sheet1 B2 into Sheet B2 and B3 which isnt what i need. Using solution 2 would result in a lot of manual entry for the amount of code i use.

Comment: The second `PasteSpecial`-statement of my **1B** example was just to show that you can issue multiple PasteSpecials after a single `Copy`. Explaining the `With` in **2** was just to show you why your line cannot work. All in all, you should get rid of all your `Copy` and `Paste`-statements and just use the syntax `Worksheets("Pack").Range("B2") = Range("B2)`.

Answer (score -1):

Change the Code to this structure and it will work

ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Copy

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Copy

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this got downvoted. i have just attempted this and it seems to achieve what i desire.

Comment: It was probably downvoted (not by me!) because **a)** it doesn't explain anything **b)** it doesn't point you to the fact that instead of using `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` it's much easier to use the simple assignment syntax `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")` and **c)** it even didn't format the code.